# Merging numpy arrays (inserting extra values into an existing array)

Tags: python, numpy, merge, plot

Use case : plotting in Matplotlib, say.

```
import numpy as np
orig = np.arange(0, 30 + 0.5, 0.5)
extra = orig - 0.01  # I'm interested in a few extra values

x = np.???(orig, extra)
```

What I want is to somehow merge (I guess a sort is also needed for the current use case) these two arrays (not always of the same size) so that I can use it for a subsequent plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you're looking for

```
x = np.sort(np.hstack((orig, extra)))
```

Here, [`hstack()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) merges the two arrays, and [`sort()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) sorts the result.